# Is there a way to isolate every device on my network?

Tags: network, network-access-control

As it is every device on my network and every app on those devices could be hacking my other devices on my network. The app I just downloaded to my iPhone might be looking for known exploits in my printer. Some game I just downloaded to my PS4 might be trying to hack my ip camera. My smart TV's new update might be trying to hack an unpacked exploit on my Linux box.

Is there some way I can configure a router such that every device is isolated from every other (can't see the other devices on the network). Then I can poke a few minor holes (like if I want my PS4 to be able to see my media server).

Answer (score 1):

That's what a firewall is for. In your case a packet filter based solution (linux with iptables or similar) is probably mostly enough but if you want to have a more granular access (i.e. only specific pages of the internal web server) you would need application level control which a packet filter does not offer. The usual home routers are mostly not suitable for this purpose because the firewall they often implement is only for separating the internal from the external network, but not for separation between internal devices.

Comment: I have seen  many home routers which have this function. However, it is only a checkbox with "Isolate clients" or something like that.

Comment: @Vilican: Yes, some might offer full isolation (sometimes only for WiFi clients) but they don't offer a granular firewall between clients so that one can allow limited interaction.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way I can configure a router such that every device is isolated from every other (can't see the other devices on the network). Then I can poke a few minor holes (like if I want my PS4 to be able to see my media server).

If you want to segregate the devices in your network, then you should consider VLANs and IP Subnetting. When correctly implemented with a router, these will make sure that your devices will have limited or no access to other devices in your own network. you will find the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/54417/best-way-to-segment-traffic-vlan-or-subnet) to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can configure a router such that every device is isolated from every other (can't see the other devices on the network) by creating VLANs. Just create as many VLANs as the number of devices, and put each device in separate VLAN.

Unless you specifically allow/route traffic between VLANs, devices in separate VLANs will not be able to communicate.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answer offers anything different from JOW's answer.

Comment: Yes , but the JOWs answer is a little ambiguous. :)